# How RCU handles the condition of a reader started reading critical section while synchronize_rcu() is waiting

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, locking, rcu

As per the RCU documentation (I believe kernel and userspace RCU frameworks are similar), `synchronize_rcu()` waits for all the readers (who started before `synchronize_rcu` was called ) to finish.
What happens to the readers which are started after `synchronize_rcu()` is waiting in its grace period?
What is the difference between the readers started after `synchronize_rcu()` returns, and readers started while `synchronize_rcu()` waits? How RCU framework handles this?

Comment: *"What happens to the readers..."* - they read. `synchronize_rcu()` just makes sure that all previous readers have exited the critical section, and then you can release the old copy of the data structure. This does not interfere with new readers.

Comment: What do you mean by "after synchronize_rcu"? After it returns or after it starting to wait? Please clarify your question

Comment: @red0ct edited my comment. The new reader (which started executing in critical section after synchronize_rcu() is waiting in its grace period) reads the new data structure? If that is the case, what is the difference between the readers started after synchronize_rcu() returns, and readers started while synchronize_rcu() waits? Both readers read the new data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The new reader (which started executing in critical section after
>   synchronize_rcu() is waiting in its grace period) reads the new data
>   structure?

All the readers entering the critical section after `rcu_assign_pointer()` read the new data structure.

> What is the difference between the readers started after
>   synchronize_rcu() returns, and readers started while synchronize_rcu()
>   waits?

All you are talking about depends on if/when the new pointer is assigned. Assigning and reading are related things.

---

`synchronize_rcu()` on Linux generally waits until all CPUs will have their [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630214/context-switch-internals) switched - it guarantees that no one who saw the old pointer doesn't use it anymore (context switch happens after reader [exits](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/rcupdate.h#L307) their critical section) - so we can free this memory. From [this post](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/RCU/whatisRCU.html):

> ..if a given CPU executes a context switch, we know that it must have
>   completed all preceding RCU read-side critical sections. Once all CPUs
>   have executed a context switch, then all preceding RCU read-side
>   critical sections will have completed.
>   So, suppose that we remove a data item from its structure and then
>   invoke synchronize_rcu(). Once synchronize_rcu() returns, we are
>   guaranteed that there are no RCU read-side critical sections holding a
>   reference to that data item, so we can safely reclaim it.

New readers know nothing about old data structure. "Swapping" of pointers is atomic.
One more time: `synchronize_rcu()` has no effect on readers - it just guarantees that after it returns, we can free the memory the pointer points to (`kfree()`).

It seems you have not explored the basics of Linux RCU.
Must read:

- [What is RCU, Fundamentally?](https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/)
- [What is RCU? Part 2: Usage](https://lwn.net/Articles/263130/)
- [RCU part 3: the RCU API](https://lwn.net/Articles/264090/)
- [What is RCU?  --  "Read, Copy, Update"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt)