# How to measure the context switching overhead of a very large program?

Tags: multithreading, profiling, perf, microbenchmark, context-switch

I am trying to measure the impact of CPU scheduler on a large AI program (https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech).

By using strace, I can see that it uses a lot of (~200) CPU threads.

I have tried using Linux Perf to measure this, but I have only been able to find the **number** of context switch events, not the **overhead** of them.

What I am trying to achieve is the total CPU core-seconds spent on context switching. Since it is a pretty large program, I would prefer non-invasive tools to avoid having to edit the source code of this program.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to measure total time in the kernel (i.e including time for kernel to perform IO) or just the time spent performing context switches?

Comment: @Noah Just the time performing context switches. 

My ultimate goal is this: I have a program that spends a lot of time in the kernel, and I want a detailed breakdown of this time (i.e. x percent spent doing syscalls, y percent spent on context-switches, etc.). I know that syscall time can be measured by `strace`. But I don't know how to measure context-swtich time.

Comment: Including time to context switch for ```syscall``` or just between threads?

Comment: Related: [FlexSC: Flexible System Call Scheduling with Exception-Less System Calls](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Soares.pdf) is a paper that has some measurements/simulations of lowered IPC *after* a system-call returns.  Even worse when migrating a thread to a new core, or switching between threads on this core, for cache locality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure most of those 200 threads are actually waiting to run at the same time, not waiting for data from a system call?  I guess you can tell from `perf stat` that context-switches are actually pretty high, but part of the question is whether they're high for the threads doing the critical work.

**The cost of a context-switch is reflected in cache misses once a thread is running again.**  (And stopping OoO exec from finding as much [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) right at the interrupt boundary).  This cost is more significant than the cost of the kernel code that saves/restores registers.  So even if there was a way to measure how much time the CPUs spent in kernel context-switch code (possible with `perf record` sampling profiler as long as your `perf_event_paranoid` setting allows recording kernel addresses), that wouldn't be an accurate reflection of the true cost.

Even making a system call has a similar (but lower and more frequent) performance cost from serializing OoO exec, as well as disturbing caches (and TLB).  There's a useful characterization of this on real modern CPUs (from 2010) in a paper by Livio & Stumm, especially the graph on the first page of IPC (instructions per cycle) dropping after a system call returns, and taking time to recover:  [FlexSC: Flexible System Call Scheduling with Exception-Less System Calls](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Soares.pdf).  (Conference presentation: https://www.usenix.org/conference/osdi10/flexsc-flexible-system-call-scheduling-exception-less-system-calls)

---

You might estimate context-switch cost by running the program on a system with enough cores not to need to context-switch much at all (e.g. a big many-core Xeon or Epyc), vs. on fewer cores but with the same CPUs / caches / inter-core latency and so on. So, on the same system with `taskset --cpu-list 0-8 ./program` to limit how many cores it can use.

Look at the total user-space CPU-seconds used: the amount higher is the extra amount of CPU time needed because of slowdowns from context switched.  The wall-clock time will of course be higher when the same work has to compete for fewer cores, but `perf stat` includes a "task-clock" output which tells you a total time in CPU-milliseconds that threads of your process spent on CPUs.  That would be constant for the same amount of work, with perfect scaling to more threads, and/or to the same threads competing for more / fewer cores.

But that would tell you about context-switch overhead on that big system with big caches and higher latency between cores than on a small desktop.

Comment: You are right, the threads could be waiting for data and voluntarily yielding the CPU, causing a context-switch. Is there a way for me to differentiate this case from an involuntary context-swtich caused by timer interrupts? I haven't been able to find a way to count timer interrupts...

Comment: @Azuresonance: counting timer interrupts wouldn't be useful anyway, since unless you're running a tickless kernel, not every timer interrupt causes a context switch.  You might get a rough idea by looking at load average (`uptime` or `top`) to see how many tasks on average are running, or would be running if they had a CPU available.  But I think that also counts tasks in D state (disk sleep); IDK if that's a factor.

Comment: @Azuresonance: I don't know how to count non-voluntary context switches.  Like maybe you could take the `perf stat` count and subtract the number of `yield()` or `futex()` system calls?  And of course sleeping because you need to wait for a lock might mean that some other thread went to sleep while holding a lock, or else it's just taking a long time inside its critical section. Sleeping while holding a lock would amplify the number of context switches caused by the code trying to use more cores than you have. (Most good multi-threaded code chooses a number of threads based on available cores)

Comment: Simliiar to your perf record method you might be able to isolate the start / end with [PERF_SAMPLE_ADDR](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html). I'm not sure how you get the address of context switch code.

Comment: @Noah: Yes, `perf record` uses `PERF_SAMPLE_ADDR` if `perf_event_paranoid` allows it.  Linux's context-switch code is `switch_to()`, called by `schedule()` [Context switch internals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12630214).   (The actual user-space register save/restore is in kernel entry/exit, though, except for SIMD/FP registers which are eagerly saved/restored on context switch in modern Linux, at least for x86.  So `switch_to()` just has to change current integer registers, including kernel stack pointer, and save/restore FP state.  And CR3 page table if new process, not just thread)

Comment: @PeterCordes So I tried your advice of `perf stat`ing the number of `yield`s, and got a very weird result that don't make any sense. I ran `perf stat 'syscalls:sys_enter_sched_yield' -e 'context-switches' ./my_program` and got 16 millions `yield`s per 3 million context-switches. How could there be more `yield`s than context-switches? I would be grateful if you have any idea.

Comment: @Azuresonance: If there aren't any other tasks ready to run (which aren't already running on another core), yield will return to the same task that called it without actually triggering a context-switch.  Or for whatever other reason the scheduler decides to keep running this task.